# How to exchange variable values between contextual filters of the same view?

Tags: views, sessions

I have a view with two Global: NULL fields as contextual filters, which use php code in their default value.
The first global null value calculates and provides an order quantity, and the second global null calculates and provides the discount percentage. Both base their calculations on values in the URL.
I store the order quantity and the discount percentage as session variables (for use in the transaction).
The calculation of the discount value depends on the quantity.

Question: How can I use the quantity (calculated in global null field 1), in the php discount percentage calculated in global null field 2?
I tried using the session variable as set in the global null field 1, but that appears not to work?

Comment: Can you please export your views code and share it with us? That will help in resolving the issue quickly.

Comment: The complete views is rather complex, so I'd focus only on the contextual filters. But here you are: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sd241cmas3skbk2/views%20export%20124262.txt

Comment: And as background information, I posted another question about the exact same view, concerning a related issue. Might be helpful to see the diagram: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/124036/how-to-get-the-highest-value-of-a-specific-field-in-a-multivalue-field-collectio